# Count number of occurances of a string in all the files in folder. Display File name, count of string in each file

Tags: powershell

I want to write a PowerShell script to count occurrences of a string in all the files in a directory.

Display the file name, occurrences of string in each file.

example output
File1.txt 3
File2.txt 4
File3.txt 5
File4.txt 2

Please help.

I tried using the below command. But it gives the total count. But need to display like above.
(gc *.txt | select-string -pattern "").length

Comment: Break your problem into steps. 1) Write code that counts and prints in one file. 2) Put that into a function where you pass the file (or name). 3) Write code to get a list of files. 4) For each of the files in the list call the function you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would solve it

```
$location='c:\somefolder'    
$word='someword'    
$countList= New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList    
$i=get-childitem $location    
foreach($a in $i){    
    $s=get-content $a.FullName          
    $j=[PSCustomObject]@{Fname=$a.Name;count=([regex]::Matches($s,$word)).Count}            
    $countList.Add($j)    }         
$countList
```

Comment: Now to use your expression, we just iterate over the child items of the folder containing the texts

`foreach($a in gci 'c:\somefolder'){$a.name +' '+(gc $a.FullName | select-string -pattern "someword").length}`